# how to zoom the image to specified coordinates in android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I would like to zoom the image to particular portion(to specified coordinates) of the image. 
I have an image, i displayed it in android image view with full screen. when i click on a button i would like to zoom the image to specified coordinates of the image.lets say coordinates i have is left:500,top:50,width:60 and height:20. I want the full image zoom to specified coordinates and fit this sub image in center of the image view.

Currently i am doing it by cropping the image to specified coordinates. I will get small image. I am displaying it in image view. But i think it is not as good solution.

Can some one help me to find the way to implement the zoom functionality.

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602465/image-crop-and-resize-in-android

Comment: Thanks Niko, it seems you suggest for crop image. but i need not to crop the image. i just zoom the image to given coordinates.

Comment: have you find the solution? please help

Comment: could you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you looking for :

```
/**
 * Set zoom to the specified scale. Image will be centered around the point
 * (focusX, focusY). These floats range from 0 to 1 and denote the focus point
 * as a fraction from the left and top of the view. For example, the top left 
 * corner of the image would be (0, 0). And the bottom right corner would be (1, 1).
 * @param scale
 * @param focusX
 * @param focusY
 * @param scaleType
 */
public void setZoom(float scale, float focusX, float focusY, ScaleType scaleType) {
    //
    // setZoom can be called before the image is on the screen, but at this point, 
    // image and view sizes have not yet been calculated in onMeasure. Thus, we should
    // delay calling setZoom until the view has been measured.
    //
    if (!onDrawReady) {
        delayedZoomVariables = new ZoomVariables(scale, focusX, focusY, scaleType);
        return;
    }

    if (scaleType != mScaleType) {
        setScaleType(scaleType);
    }
    resetZoom();
    scaleImage(scale, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2, true);
    matrix.getValues(m);
    m[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = -((focusX * getImageWidth()) - (viewWidth * 0.5f));
    m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = -((focusY * getImageHeight()) - (viewHeight * 0.5f));
    matrix.setValues(m);
    fixTrans();
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

for more info you can refer :

[This link Github can help you more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279087/touch-point-coordinates-with-respect-to-image-after-pinch-zoom)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279087/touch-point-coordinates-with-respect-to-image-after-pinch-zoom)

Edit :

please refer this youll get your answer :

[The Answer for your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451763/correct-way-to-use-a-matrix-to-zoom-an-imageview-around-a-focal-point)

Comment: Yes, I have seen this code. If I am not wrong, 'scale' param decides the zoom level. But what all I need is to find that zoom (scale). What say ?

Comment: According to your question the above answer is right... now in comment yoy are asking a different one eheh

Comment: That's not right. Try to understand my comment - this method takes scale (zoom) as parameter and that is what I WANT to calculate with the help of coordinates. Or if you think I am still not getting it, try to explain little more. I appreciate.

Comment: Ill try to explain it tomorrow right now I dont have laptop

Answer (score 0):

Use this Custom ImageView class for you Image View. Then If you want to keep Pinch Zoom then you can use that as well otherwise remove all gestures from it. You can see a "Double Tap method" in the class given below. Just call this method code on the click of your button.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace, origRedundantXSpace, origRedundantYSpace;;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
static final float SAVE_SCALE = 1f;
float saveScale = SAVE_SCALE;

float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight, origScale, origBottom,origRight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            boolean onDoubleTapEvent = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            if (onDoubleTapEvent) {
                // Reset Image to original scale values
                mode = NONE;
                bottom = origBottom;
                right = origRight;
                last = new PointF();
                start = new PointF();
                m = new float[9];
                saveScale = SAVE_SCALE;
                matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.setScale(origScale, origScale);
                matrix.postTranslate(origRedundantXSpace, origRedundantYSpace);
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            } 


            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                    float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                    if (scaleWidth < width) {
                        deltaX = 0;
                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                    } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                        deltaY = 0;
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                    } else {
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);

                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                    }
                    matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    performClick();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();

            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(
                Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width
                - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height
                - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width
                || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2,
                    height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    // Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = SAVE_SCALE;
    origScale = scale;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
    redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

    origRedundantXSpace = redundantXSpace;
    origRedundantYSpace = redundantYSpace;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height
            - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    origRight = right;
    origBottom = bottom;
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: you mean the code under if (onDoubleTapEvent)  ? If so,  I think it does not calculate the scale/zoom-factor by taking focus point (TRANS_X, TRANS_Y) and/or width and height of image (in pixels).

Comment: You have to give your specific values for sx and sy, till those you want to zoom your image, in the "setScale()" method.

matrix.setScale(x coordinate , y coordinate);

Comment: Thanks for response. You mean keep setting the scale till I zoom into coordinates I want to zoom ? I was thinking of that too but how do we find if the coordinates are now fell within view and so stop scaling ?
Also, the coordinates I want to zoom may be within view but I want to zoom out so that will be fit to view and visible properly. Please take a look at bounty comment added under question.